# How to know if the sentence asks for an action?

Tags: word-usage

In a sentence like the one below:

'10월 납부하실 금액 안내드립니다'

How the payment will be made, how do I know?

Sure the payment is to be made by the person who received the message, but then will the payment be automatically deducted from the account or the person has to make the payment via transfer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence literally means, (intentionally translating too literal)

> We notify you of the information about the amount of money that has to be paid for October."

No more information is conveyed by the given Korean sentence. The transaction might be automatic (if you have that previously set-up), or you might have to go and make the transfer yourself.

It has nothing to do with the sentence itself, and the sender of the message should be asked for further information.